# Trying to insert data from a drop-down list as a foreign key in another table. Data not inserted

Tags: php, database, mysqli

I been trying to figure out where my mistake is without success. I get no reported errors. I want to insert data into the supplier table from a PHP form. `id_drugstore` is a foreign key into the `supplier` table and can be chosen form a drop-down list (*drop-down is working perfect*). Another date is filled in by the user, except `id_supplier`.

```
<?
   error_reporting(-1);
   $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "retete");
   if(mysqli_connect_errno())
   {
    echo "Nu ma pot conecta la baza de date medical:" .mysqli_connect_error(); 
   }
    if(isset($_POST['submit']){

    $id_drugstore=$_POST['id_drugstore'];
    $name_suplier=$_POST['name_suplier'];
    $country_supplier=$_POST['county_supplier'];
    $county_supplier=$_POST['county_supplier'];
    $town_supplier=$_POST['town_supplier'];
    $street_supplier=$_POST['street_supplier'];
    $bank_suplier=$_POST['bank_suplier'];
    $no_cont_Bank=$_POST['$no_cont_Bank'];

    $qry=mysqli_query("INSERT INTO supplier `VALUES('sss','%$id_drugstore%',$_POST['name_suplier']','$_POST['county_supplier']','$_POST['county_supplier']','$_POST['town_supplier']','$_POST['street_supplier']','$_POST['bank_suplier']','$_POST['$no_cont_Bank']";`
    $inserted=($qry,$conn);
    if($inserted){
    echo "Datele au fost inserate cu suucess";
    }else{
    echo "datele nu au putut fi salvate in baza de date".mysqli_error($conn);
    }
    }
    mysqli_close($conn);
    }
    ?>

    <body>
    <div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="container">
    <h4 class="display-5">Adaugare Furnizori in baza de date</h4>
    <p class="lead">Completati formularul de mai jos</p>
    </div>
    </div>
    <form action="AdaugareFurnizori.php" method="POST">
    <div class="form-row">
    <div class="col-md-2 mb-3">
    <label for="validationServer01">Farmacie</label>
    <select name="name_drugstore">
    <option>Selecteaza farmacie</option>
    <?php
    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "retete");
    if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
    echo "Nu ma pot conecta la baza de date medical:".mysqli_connect_error(); 
    }           
    $q=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM drugstore")or die(mysqli_error());

    $c=mysqli_num_rows($q);
    if($c==0){
    echo 'Nu exista farmacie in baza de date';
    }else{
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($q)){
    $id_drugstore=$row['id_drugstore'];
    $name_drugstore=$row['name_drugstore'];
    echo "<option value='$id_drugstore'>$id_drugstore/$name_drugstore<option>
    }
    }
    mysqli_close($conn);
    ?>
    </select>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
    <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
    <label for="validationServer01">Denumire Furnizori</label>
    <input type="text" name="name_suplier" class="form-control is-valid" id = "validationServer01" placeholder="Denumire Furnizor" required>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
    <div class="col-md-2 mb-3">
    <label for="validationServer02">Tara</label>
    <input type="text" name="country_supplier" class="form-control is-valid" id="validationServer02" placeholder="Tara" required>
    <div class="invalid-feedback">
    Va rugam sa introduceti tara.
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 mb-3">
    <label for="validationServer03">Judet</label>
    <input type="text" name="county_supplier" class="form-control is-valid" id="validationServer03" placeholder="Judet" required>
    <div class="invalid-feedback">
    Va rugam sa introduceti judetul.
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 mb-3">
    <label for="validationServer04">Oras</label>
    <input type="text" name="town_supplier"class="form-control is-valid" id="validationServer04" placeholder="Oras" required>
    <div class="invalid-feedback">
    Va rugam sa introduceti orasul.
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 mb-3">
    <label for="validationServer05">Strada si numar</label>
    <input type="text" name="street_supplier" class="form-control is-valid" id="validationServer05" placeholder="Strada" required>
    <div class="invalid-feedback">
    Va rugam sa introduceti strada.
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 mb-3">
    <label for="validationServer04">Banca</label>
    <input type="text" name="bank_suplier"class="form-control is-valid" id="validationServer04" placeholder="Denumire Banca" required>
    <div class="invalid-feedback">
    Va rugam sa introduceti banca.
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 mb-3">
    <label for="validationServer05">Cont</label>
    <input type="text" name="no_cont_Bank" class="form-control is-valid" id="validationServer05" placeholder="Numar Cont" required>
    <div class="invalid-feedback">
    Va rugam sa introduceti numarul contului.
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="submit">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit form</button>
    </div>
    </div>
    </form>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: have u checked whether your submit button is being clicked on not?and u also have to give connection string with the mysqli_query() method

Comment: Yes, I did that too, but nothing happen.

Answer (score 0):

That query looks strange:

```
$qry=mysqli_query("INSERT INTO supplier `VALUES('sss','%$id_drugstore%',$_POST['name_suplier']','$_POST['county_supplier']','$_POST['county_supplier']','$_POST['town_supplier']','$_POST['street_supplier']','$_POST['bank_suplier']','$_POST['$no_cont_Bank']";`
```

- Remove the backticks `
- Missing an opening `'` before `$_POST['name_suplier']'`
- All of your `$_POST` variables in that string will never get replaced, put them in curly brackts: `{$_POST['name_suplier']}`
- Make sure you have no typos in there `name_suplier` vs. `town_supplier`
- Missing a closing bracket at the end of the query AND as a closing bracket for `mysql_query()`

Side note: Shouldn't there be a list of fields in that INSERT too?

Comment: is the change that I made : $qry=mysqli_query("INSERT INTO supplier (`id_supplier`, `id_drugstore`, `name_suplier`, `country_supplier`, `county_supplier`, `town_supplier`, `street_supplier`, `bank_suplier`, `no_cont_Bank`) VALUES
 
 ('sss','%$id_drugstore%','{$_POST['name_suplier']}','{$_POST['country_supplier']}','{$_POST['county_supplier']}','{$_POST['town_supplier']}','{$_POST['street_supplier']}','{$_POST['bank_suplier']}','{$_POST['$no_cont_Bank']}'");
 $inserted=($qry,$conn); and still nothing happen

Answer (score -1):

your code should be.
If your supplier table have all this field which you are going to insert then this will works fine but if u skip any of the field then mysqli_query does not work

```
$qry="INSERT INTO supplier `VALUES('sss','%$id_drugstore%',$_POST['name_suplier']','$_POST['county_supplier']','$_POST['county_supplier']','$_POST['town_supplier']','$_POST['street_supplier']','$_POST['bank_suplier']','$_POST['$no_cont_Bank']')";

$inserted=mysqli_query($qry,$conn);
```

Comment: I copy and paste the insert query from phpmyadmin, with all field in it, I replace '$_POST['id_supplier']' with '%$id_drugstore%', but nothing, no errors, but data are not inserted.

Comment: does your query run in phpmyadmin? have you tried this way?put your query with acutal value and then execute the query and then see is there any errors displayed or  not

Comment: It runs like this : INSERT INTO `supplier` (`id_supplier`, `id_drugstore`, `name_suplier`, `country_supplier`, `county_supplier`, `town_supplier`, `street_supplier`, `bank_suplier`, `no_cont_Bank`) VALUES (NULL, '1', 'Phonix', 'Romania', 'Timis', 'Timisoara', 'CDLoga 17', 'BCR', 'RO77BRDE450SV65683066666'); No errors

Comment: and it's being inserted through phpmyadmin?

Comment: i thought your  id_supplier is primary key which will never being a null

Comment: yess Mahi Parmar I can insert it though php ad id_supplier is auto increment.